# Поменять местами два элемента списка

Tags: python

Как поменять местами два элемента списка по их номерам, например второй и пятый элементы списка:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

=>

```
l = [1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: `l[1], l[4] = l[4], l[1]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
l[1], l[4] = l[4], l[1]
```